# Run a function when celery task correctly ends in Django

Tags: django, celery

I'm using Django and Celery and I'm correctly executing Celery tasks with

```
@shared_task(bind=True)
def start_serial_acquisition(self, idObj, porta_COM):
```

and

```
start_serial_acquisition.delay(instance.pk, porta_COM)
```

I would like to call or execute a specific function when a celery task ends with the SUCCESS flag.

Are there any decorators like Django `@receiver(pre/post,)` as I can't find something similar

I need to be executed after the tasks end so, a solution that launch the function as last line of the celery task is not suitable for me

Comment: Tasks are independant. It kind of sounds like what you need is a pub/sub architecture.

Comment: @michjnich it seems you're wrong

Comment: Not really. SIgnals are in general a bad idea. It's very easy to lose track of what triggers what. But sure, be rude to somebody trying to make a helpful suggestion, see how far that gets you in life.

Comment: @michjnich rude? Doesn't seem to me honestly as there were an answer to my question but, from your comment, it seems it wasn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that Celery has this kind of signals as [documentation explains](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/signals.html)

```
from celery.signals import task_success

@task_success.connect
def task_completed_handler(sender=None, headers=None, body=None, **kwargs):
    print(sender.request.id)
```